# Create zip with directories

Tags: zip, .net-4.5, directory

Is it possible to create a zip with a directory(s) inside it using the .net 4.5 [System.IO.Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z72378a.aspx) classes.

I can't seem to find anything that suggests you can.

I have a number of dynamically generated files as byte arrays I want to add to a sub folder in the zip.

The code I have so far is

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
            using (var zip =new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create,true))
            {
                var zipEntry = zip.CreateEntry(string.Format("{0} Manual.pdf", plant.Name));

                using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(zipEntry.Open()))
                {
                    writer.Write(manualPdf);
                }

                var attachments = GetAttachments(manual.Headings);


                foreach (var attachment in attachments.Where(attachment => attachment != null && attachment.Data != null))
                {
                    var attachmentEntry = zip.CreateEntry(attachment.FileName);
                    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(attachmentEntry.Open()))
                    {
                        writer.Write(attachment.Data);
                    }
                }

            }
```

In this case I would like the loop for attachments to be in a subdirectory of the zip. the list of attachments is a list of byte[]

Comment: Try with prefixing the filenames in the zip with the directory name. Try both windows and/or unix directory separators (/ and \). Just test in case you not 100% know. You should be able to do it in less than 5 minutes I assume, right? If that code does not work, you can even post it here. And you can also document what you've tried so far. The more information you provide the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your folder name in of the file name. Here's an example of a folder called Test.

```
foreach (var attachment in attachments.Where(attachment => attachment != null && attachment.Data != null))
            {
                var attachmentEntry = zip.CreateEntry(@"Test/" + attachment.FileName);
                using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(attachmentEntry.Open()))
                {
                    writer.Write(attachment.Data);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Warning: Using "\" in the path will produce the wrong contents when unzipped on Mac OSX or other flavors of *nix.  Please update the answer to use "/" instead which we just tested and works on Windows and Mac.